# isProviderEnabled() never getting called android

Tags: java, android, networking, location

I am writting code for getting current location (latitude and longitude) of my phone. I display a toast whether Network Location service is provided by the phone or not. This toast doesn't show up ever. The other question is, for getting current location using `Network_location`, will the app use phone's `gprs/internet` or not?

I have created the instance of this class in the main activity and then get data using Latitude and Longitude variables of this class, in another class which extends `broadcast reciever` .

```
public class GpsClass extends Activity{

public static String Latitude="";
public static String Longitude=""; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() { // anonymous class

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location currentLocation) {

            double lat= currentLocation.getLatitude();

            Latitude = Double.toString(lat);

            double longt= currentLocation.getLongitude();

            Longitude = Double.toString(longt);

        }
    };


    manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);

    if(manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network enabled", 0).show();
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network not enabled", 0).show();

 }

}
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Regards

Comment: Try adding Log instead of Toast, and check if it appears.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are passing 0 for duration i.e. last parameter of makeText() method.
Try passing `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` or `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`.

```
if(manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: no. It doesn't have to do anything with that. All other toast in my app also have 0 as duration and they work fine!

Comment: Okay I saw in documentation & found out that the value 0 is for Toast.LENGTH_SHORT & value 1 is for Toast.LENGTH_LONG. So definitely passing 0 as third parameter is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411998/why-isproviderenabled-method-always-return-true-even-inside-the-building) can help you to get answer to your first question.

The answer to your second question is - No, the app will not use phone's gprs/internet for getting location through network provider.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is setting 0 for duration.
This is a sample example:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            currentLocation = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            // Set Toast Here To Diplay location    
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

    };
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
       //10000 means request update every 10 sec
       //10 tell listener that if location change more than 10m then run locationChanged method
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 10, locationListener);
    } else {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000, 10, locationListener);
    }
```